# How to select related with existing object in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have existing `user` object that have many-many fields through `select_related` and `prefetch_related`:

```
user = models.User.objects.first().select_related(...).prefetch_related(...)
```

I need to select articles of this user **through** `Article` model (no `user.article_set`):

```
articles = models.Article.objects.filter(user=user)
```

And i want `articles` to have the existing `user` object, for example (these examples doesn't work):

```
articles = models.Article.objects.filter(user=user).select_related(user)
```

or

```
articles = models.Article.objects.filter(user=user).annotate(user=user)
```

How is this possible to do?

Answer (score -2):

So Im guessing you want something like this:

I guess you have your Article Model with a user FK or something like that.
In that user attribute you should put a related_name something like (users_articles)

With that in mind:

```
articles = user.users_articles
```

The second part I dont understood, but i guess you want to place like in a list your articles with its user so

```
for article in articles:
    user = article.user
```

I hope that helped